# Downloads folder shows music information

Tags: windows-7

For some reason, my downloads folder thinks it's a music folder, and it's changed to let me sort it by things such as album name and contributing artists. [This](http://picpaste.com/pics/downloads_problem-rPmnEAuI.1433092330.png) is how my downloads folder is organized now, and [this](http://picpaste.com/pics/what_i_want-YHk8xiLd.1433092337.png) is what I want it to look like (taken from my documents folder). How can I accomplish this? I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: If you right-click on the column header bar, you will see which columns have been selected. Simply tick those you want and clear those you don't want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right click on the Downloads folder and click on properties.

Then click the 'Customize" tab and select "General items" in the "Optimize this folder for:" combo box to reset it to the default, or select "Documents" if you prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

Additional answer: If you want to set all folders to be 'General Items' rather than automatically-choosing, run the following from the command line (with Administrative privileges):

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell" /V FolderType /T REG_SZ /D NotSpecified /F

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

Source: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15699-folder-template-default.html